# What would be that relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have the following classes:

```
class MockQuestion < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :mock
    belongs_to :question
end

class Mock < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :mock_questions
    has_many :answers
end

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :mock_questions
    has_many :answers
end

class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :question
    belongs_to :mock
end
```

Since an answer may belong to a Question and a Mock, I would like to connect it to the MockQuestion with same Mock and Question.

I can query it by:

```
Answers.where(question_id: question_id, mock_id: mock_id)
```

But I would like to do something as

```
MockQuestion.answers
```

Is there any relationship I can use to do that?

P.S.: the answers table has both "mock_id" and "question_id"

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you create `self.answers` in your `MockQuestion` class as:

```
def answers
  Answers.where(mock_id: self.mock.id, question_id self.question.id)
end
```

And I don't think that kind of relationship is possible. Hence the alternative method

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was using. But since it's not a relationship, I can't eager load it.

Comment: You can use rails join command for eager loading in this case, here is a good link http://blog.bigbinary.com/2013/07/01/preload-vs-eager-load-vs-joins-vs-includes.html, that will get you started.